# DHCP fallback based on /etc/hosts lookup of your hostname

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, hosts-file, default-settings

I have a Kubuntu box (12.04) which usually gets its IP via DHCP. However, it also has a hosts file with some entries in case the DHCP+DNS server fails. Now, if there is no DHCP available, I want the machine to look itself up (by hostname) in the hosts file, and choose its IP based on that.

Now, if I wanted to use a fixed address, without a lookup into /etc/hosts, I could add a fallback lease with a pre-specified IP address to `/etc/dhclient.conf`; but that's not quite what I need.

I'm sure this can be done with complex dhclient hooks; but I'm also sure someone has thought about this and implemented it already...

Comment: What's the use of this?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: This will go into a clone image. I expect users deploying the cloned partitions to change the hostname, but not to start messing around with IPs. I know a better solution is to deploy something like puppet, but like I said - the assumption is that the server(s) are down.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for **lease** section on *dhclient.conf*.

For example in */etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf*:

```
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 192.33.137.200;
  medium "link0 link1";
  host-name "andare.swiftmedia.com";
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option broadcast-address 192.33.137.255;
  option routers 192.33.137.250;
  option domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
  renew 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
  rebind 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
  expire 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. That is, it will use an IP address I've manually written into `dhclient.conf`, it will not look up the hostname in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: cat /etc/hosts | grep \`hostname -f\` | egrep -v "^127"

Comment: Yes, but I need to have dhclient run that script at some point.

Comment: otherwise it is impossible, I can draft this sctipt